# Differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y_1=3 \sin (2t)$ is solution of $ay''+by'+cy= 7 \cos (2t)$ and $y_2=5e^{2t}$ is solution of $ay''+by'+cy=10e^{2t}$ then what is solution to the $ay''+by'+cy=\frac{\cos(2t)}{2}+30 e^{2t}$

**My Work:**

$ay''+by'+cy=\frac{\cos(2t)}{2}+30 e^{2t}$ suppose we apply Linear  operator 
then 
$L(ay''+by'+cy)=L(\frac{\cos(2t)}{2}+30 e^{2t})=\frac{1}{2}L(\cos (2t)+30 L(e^{2t})$

i cant go further

Comment: it is going to be some linear combination of $y_1$ and $y_2.$ In other words, look for solutions in the form of $a(3\sin(2t))+b(5e^{2t}).$

Comment: @dezdichado...i am little confusing can you give some more hint

Comment: @suresh Write $y=3a \sin 2t + 5 b e^{2t}$ and then apply $L(3a \sin 2t + 5 b e^{2t})$ and find constraints on $a$ and $b$ that solve the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, your notation not. The linear operator is $L(y)=ay''+by'+cy$ and your assumptions are
$$
L(3\sin(2t))=7\cos(2t)\\
L(5e^{2t})=10e^{2t}
$$

Now by linearity you will want to divide the first identity by $14$ and multiply the second by $3$ and add all together.